# php: newbie question about modrewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i've started using modrewrite under php - i wrote an .htaccess file and defined some rules.

but the main question is - how would i do the "opposite thing" of creating the modrewrite-links inside my web?

eg. i'm using this original url inside my website: /search.php?par1=abc&par2=def&par3=ghi
the correspondending modrewrite url would be /go/find/something/here/index.html

so i'd need to replace all html-links in my web using the ugly url with the mod-rewrite url.
what's the easiest way to do this? (function for creating urls, using a database ..)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this should be a migration job, only done once, go for search/replace. Using a function or database would mean you have to do the migration for each request to your app. Which seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

A function. Simply because that way you can replace what the function does with minimal changes to other parts of the website. This is, for example, [the way Drupal does it](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url).